# R. Populate missing dates by two fields and some null values

Tags: r, date, tidyr, populate

I need to populate my data with new rows based on date. I discovered "complete seq.Date" from tidyr but I am getting a error. Below is a sample of my data.

```
  Hospital Room                  dt
1        1  100 2023-05-24 10:08:38
2        1  100 2023-05-24 10:09:36
3        1  200                <NA>
4        1  300 2023-05-24 13:51:10
5        2  145 2023-05-24 18:51:10
6        2  145 2023-05-24 20:51:10
7        2  100                <NA>
```

```
d1 <- data.frame(Hospital = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,2),
                 Room = c(100, 100, 200, 300, 145, 145, 100),
                 dt = as.POSIXct(c('2023-04-24 10:08:38',
                                   '2023-05-10 10:09:36', '', '2023-05-10 13:51:10',
                                   '2023-04-20 18:51:10', '2023-04-24 20:51:10',''),
                                 format="%Y-%M-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

The goal is that every hospital room have date values from 04/24/2023 to 05/10/2023 (min and max dates). Below is my attempt.

```
d2 <- d1 %>%
  mutate(Date2 = as.Date(dt)) %>%
  complete(Date2 = seq.Date(min(Date2, na.rm=T), max(Date2, na.rm=T), by="day"), Hospital, Room)
```

I added na.rm=T because I was getting a error message "'to must be a finite number". Although I get results, they are wrong. The combinations of date, hospital a room are incorrect. I believe this has to do because I have two "by" fields: hospital and room.

Thanks!

Comment: Hospital 2 Room 100 has no valid timestamps, what dates should be filled in there?

Comment: The same dates. All dates from 04/24/2023 to 05/10/2023.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. First I created a date and ID variable (using Hospital and Room). See the code below.

```
library(dplyr)
d1 <- d1 %>%
  mutate(ID = paste(Hospital, Room, sep = "-"),
         dt2 = as.Date(dt)) %>%
  complete(dt2 = seq.Date(min(dt2, na.rm=T), max(dt2, na.rm=T), by="day"), ID) %>%
  arrange(ID, dt2) %>%
  select(ID, Hospital, Room, dt2)
```

What I need now is to fill the NAs with their corresponding Hospital and Room value. I tried the fill function but it didn't work. Any ideas?
Thanks!
ex.

```
    ID    Hospital  Room dt2         
1 1-100        1   100 2023-05-10
2 1-100       NA    NA 2023-05-11
3 1-100       NA    NA 2023-05-12
4 1-100       NA    NA 2023-05-13
5 1-100       NA    NA 2023-05-14
6 1-100       NA    NA 2023-05-15
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `crossing` instead?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
alldates <- seq(as.Date(min(d1$dt, na.rm=TRUE)), as.Date(max(d1$dt, na.rm=TRUE)), by = "days")
distinct(d1, Hospital, Room) %>%
  crossing(Date = alldates)
# # A tibble: 80 × 3
#    Hospital  Room Date      
#       <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
#  1        1   100 2023-05-10
#  2        1   100 2023-05-11
#  3        1   100 2023-05-12
#  4        1   100 2023-05-13
#  5        1   100 2023-05-14
#  6        1   100 2023-05-15
#  7        1   100 2023-05-16
#  8        1   100 2023-05-17
#  9        1   100 2023-05-18
# 10        1   100 2023-05-19
# # ℹ 70 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: I don't think this is working. it is giving hospital and room combinations that are incorrect.    ex. hospital 1  room 145.  there is no room 145 for hospital 1.

Comment: not enough rows for certain groups. ex.  hospital 2  room 145

Comment: See again, @mar355

Comment: You mention `expand` but you are using `crossing`.

Comment: spiral dev, thanks @MAurélio